# Vector of structs c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am having an issue with creating a vector of structs. In my function AddApp I am unable to "push_back" the newly allocated struct into the vector. I get the error message "Invalid Arguments". I looked around to see if someone had a similar issue but nothing that helped. Can anyone point out whats the flaw in my logic? Thx.

```
class AppHolder
{
private:
    struct Info
    {
    int refNumber;
    string name;
    string link;
    };

vector<Info> dataBase;

public:
    void AddApp(int ,string ,string );
};

void AppHolder::AddApp(int R, string N, string L)
{
Info *newApp = new Info;
newApp -> name = N;
newApp -> link = L;
newApp -> refNumber = R;

dataBase.push_back(newApp);
}
```

Comment: You know how `Type` differs from `Type*`, right?

Comment: You try to push back a pointer but the vector is templated for instances of your struct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason your code fails is that `std::vector<Info>::push_back` requires that you pass it object of type `Info`, but you pass `Info*`.

We can solve this by using `Info` objects directly instead of using pointers to `new`ed variables:

```
void AppHolder::AddApp(int R, string N, string L)
{
    Info newApp;
    newApp.name = N;
    newApp.link = L;
    newApp.refNumber = R;
    dataBase.push_back(newApp);
}
```

`Info* newApp = new Info;` declares a pointer to Info, and initializing it with address of dynamically created object of type `Info`, which must be deleted later, or destructor won't be called and memory won't be released.

`Info newApp;` declares an automatic variable of type `Info` which destructor is called at the end of scope, and its memory will be released.

Using `new` with pointers is discouraged in modern C++, as it requires manual `delete` of pointers, it's exception-unsafe (if exception is thrown before delete, resources aren't deleted) and involves writing a lot of code (copy constructor, copy assignment operator, destructor, move constructor, move assignment operator) to ensure your class works correctly. There are, however, situations where pointer usage is required (storing instances of derived classes in containers), in that case you want to use *smart pointers* which can manage resources for you.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration

```
vector<Info> dataBase;
```

Declares a vector that takes `Info` **objects**. In the initialiser,

```
Info *newApp = new Info;
newApp -> name = N;
newApp -> link = L;
newApp -> refNumber = R;

dataBase.push_back(newApp);
```

The statement `dataBase.push_back(newApp);` tries to push a **pointer to an `Info` structure** on to the vector (but your vector wants objects, not pointers to objects).

So, you either need to decalre a vector of pointers to `Info` structures - `vector<Info *>` - and remember to **free each pointer in the class destructor**. Or, just create an `Info` structure on the stack (i.e. an actual object) and push that onto the vector (which will create a copy of the struct inside the vector - will use default struct copy constructor in your case, which is fine because the struct doesn't contain pointers etc or anything that requires or does not support a deep copy).

The latter method is safer, because you don't have to remember to free anything, and also more efficient in this case, probably, because although you're copying a structure, you don't make an expensive system call to the OS to make the memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your compiler is complaining is that you defined dataBase to be a vector of `Info` instances, and you are trying to push a pointer to an `Info` instance.

Changing the `vector<Info>` declaration to `vector<Info*>` is one way, or change the `AddApp` method:

```
void AppHolder::AddApp(int R, string N, string L)
{
    Info newApp;
    newApp.name = N;
    newApp.link = L;
    newApp.refNumber = R;

    dataBase.push_back(newApp);
}
```

As others have pointed out, the use of `new` in C++ is discouraged, so keeping your container definition is preferred.  Change your implementation to use the correct type.

A commenter clarifies why one should be careful when using `new` in C++.

Comment: It is not that use of `new` is discouraged (it exists for a reason), but that allocating memory manually should be done carefully to prevent memory leaks (and other hard to find/fix memory-related bugs).  Typically, a good way to make sure memory is cleaned up properly (in a case like this) is to use `unique_ptr` (or one of the other smart pointer wrapper templates) instead of raw pointers.  That said, I like the non-heap answers to this particular question better than the unnecessary memory allocation versions.

Answer (score 0):

You must turn this:

```
vector<Info> dataBase;
```

into this:

```
vector<Info*> dataBase;
```

as you want to push_back a pointer, and vector is declared to take objects.

Comment: -1: storing raw pointers in containers is always a failure (which involves writing code to satisfy Rule of Three/Five, exception-unsafe code). There are always better alternatives than doing it manually.